# JTextField dispatchEvent Doesn't Work, But Works For TextField

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jtextfield, dispatchevent

In my program, I wanted to invoke an `ActionEvent` on a `TextField` named `descField`, when the focus is lost.  I used `dispatchEvent` successfully.  When I changed the `TextField` to a `JTextField`, it doesn't work.  I would be grateful for some help (I am an amateur with Java).  Here is the dispatcher which is the `focusLost` method of my `JTextField`:

```
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent f) {
        ActionEvent action = new ActionEvent(descField, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "focus_lost");
        descField.dispatchEvent(action); // Causes actionPerformed to be invoked
        // Does not work with JTextArea
    } //focusLost
```

How can I make it work using `JTextField`, instead of `TextField`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
*"I would be grateful for some help"* I'd be grateful for a question.  What is your question?

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I do not know what an SSCCE is and this is my first question.  The question is how can I make it work using JTextField, instead of TextField?

Comment: *"I do not know what an SSCCE is.."*  That is why I linked to the document that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in the ActionEvent in a seperate method in this listener class, and just invoke that from both the actionPerformed and the focusLost methods instead.  Now works fine with a JTextField.  I think most people would do that anyway.  The actionPerformed code was quite lengthy.